# MATLAB: how to stack up arrays "shape-agnostically"?

Tags: matlab

Suppose that `f` is a function of one parameter whose output is an *n*-dimensional (*m*<sub>1</sub> × *m*<sub>2</sub>… × *m*<sub>*n*</sub>) array, and that `B` is a vector of length *k* whose elements are all valid arguments for `f`.

> I am looking for a convenient, and more importantly, "shape-agnostic", MATLAB expression (or recipe) for producing the (*n*+1)-dimensional (*m*<sub>1</sub> × *m*<sub>2</sub> ×…× *m*<sub>*n*</sub> × *k*) array obtained by "stacking" the *k* *n*-dimensional arrays `f(b)`, where the parameter `b` ranges over `B`.

To do this in `numpy`, I would use an expression like this one:

```
C = concatenate([f(b)[..., None] for b in B], -1)
```

In case it's of any use, I'll unpack this numpy expression below (see **APPENDIX**), but the feature of it that I want to emphasize now is that *it is entirely agnostic about the shapes/sizes of* `f(b)` *and* `B`.  For the types of applications I have in mind, the ability to write such "shape-agnostic" code is of *utmost importance*.  (I stress this point because much MATLAB code I come across for doing this sort of manipulation is decidedly not "shape-agnostic", and I don't know how to make it so.)

---

**APPENDIX**

In general, if `A` is a numpy array, then the expression `A[..., None]` can be thought as "reshaping" `A` so that it gets one extra, trivial, dimension.  Thus, if `f(b)` is an *n*-dimensional (*m*<sub>1</sub> × *m*<sub>2</sub>… × *m*<sub>*n*</sub>) array, then, `f(b)[..., None]` is the corresponding (*n*+1)-dimensional (*m*<sub>1</sub> × *m*<sub>2</sub> ×…× *m*<sub>*n*</sub> × 1) array.  (The reason for adding this trivial dimension will become clear below.)

With this clarification out of the way, the meaning of the first argument to `concatenate`, namely:

```
[f(b)[..., None] for b in B]
```

is not too hard to decipher.  It is a standard Python "list comprehension", and it evaluates to the sequence of the *k* (*n*+1)-dimensional (*m*<sub>1</sub> × *m*<sub>2</sub> ×…× *m*<sub>*n*</sub> × 1) arrays `f(b)[..., None]`, as the parameter `b` ranges over the vector `B`.

The second argument to `concatenate` is the "axis" along which the concatenation is to be performed, expressed as the index of the corresponding dimension of the arrays to be concatenated.  In this context, the index -1 plays the same role as the `end` keyword does in MATLAB.  Therefore, the expression

```
concatenate([f(b)[..., None] for b in B], -1)
```

says "concatenate the arrays `f(b)[..., None]` along their last dimension".  It is in order to provide this "last dimension" to concatenate over that it becomes necessary to reshape the `f(b)` arrays (with, e.g., `f(b)[..., None]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing that is:

```
 % input:
 f=@(x) x*ones(2,2)
 b=1:3;
 %%%%
 X=arrayfun(f,b,'UniformOutput',0);
 X=cat(ndims(X{1})+1,X{:});
```

Maybe there are more elegant solutions?

Comment: To be really shape-agnostic, i.e. permit arrays of different dimensions in `X`, you can use `max(cellfun(@ndims,X))+1` for the dimension argument.

Answer (score 1):

Shape agnosticity is an important difference between the philosophies underlying NumPy and Matlab; it's a lot harder to accomplish in Matlab than it is in NumPy. And in my view, shape agnosticity is a **bad thing**, too -- the shape of matrices has *mathematical meaning*. If some function or class were to completely ignore the shape of the inputs, or change them in a way that is not in accordance with mathematical notations, then that function destroys part of the language's functionality and intent.

In programmer terms, it's an actually useful feature designed to prevent shape-related bugs. Granted, it's often a "programmatic inconvenience", but that's no reason to adjust the language. It's really all in the mindset.

Now, having said that, I doubt an elegant solution for your problem exists in Matlab :) My suggestion would be to stuff all of the requirements into the function, so that you don't have to do any post-processing:

```
f = @(x) bsxfun(@times, permute(x(:), [2:numel(x) 1]), ones(2,2, numel(x)) )
```

Now obviously this is not *quite* right, since `f(1)` doesn't work and `f(1:2)` does something other than `f(1:4)`, so obviously some tinkering has to be done. But as the ugliness of this oneliner already suggests, a dedicated function might be a better idea. The one suggested by Oli is pretty decent, provided you lock it up in a function of its own:

```
function y = f(b)

    g = @(x)x*ones(2,2); %# or whatever else you want

    y = arrayfun(g,b, 'uni',false);
    y = cat(ndims(y{1})+1,y{:});
end
```

so that `f(b)` for any `b` produces the right output.